# Importing timestamps from MySQL to Postgres

Tags: mysql, postgresql, datetime, import

I'm migrating from MySQL to Postgres using `mysqldump` and `psql` and getting this error:

> ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00" at character 52
>   STATEMENT:  INSERT INTO "cron" VALUES (1,'2015-07-11 05:21:40','0000-00-00 00:00:00',2,58,'updateBid','plus',NULL,NULL),(2,'2015-07-11 05:21:40','0000-00-00

The MySQL table looks like

```
CREATE TABLE "cron" (
  "id" int(11) NOT NULL,
  "execute_after" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  "executed_at" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
```

The Postgres table looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE "cron" (
  "id" int NOT NULL,
  "execute_after" timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  "executed_at" timestamp,
```

How can I automatically import this field?

Comment: I presume (from the fact that `executed_at` is nullable in Postgres, but not in MySQL) that you wish for such zero values to become `NULL` in Postgres?  If so, you could either search/replace in the `.sql` file; or first update the data in MySQL before exporting (perhaps by copying the data into a temporary table if you don't wish to alter the original).

Answer (score 1):

Ok I solved it with `sed`:

> mysqldump --compress --compatible postgresql --no-create-info --compact dbname | sed $'s/\'0000-00-00 00:00:00\'/NULL/g' | psql dbname